# Selected text alignment for Android spinner

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to align selected text of a Spinner in Android. It should align to the matching indentation of the other TextView and EditText in the layout.

What I have in my layout:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Btik.png

What i want to do:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j75Qz.png

My Layout code:

```
 <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
        android:entries="@array/bank_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/bank_prompt"
        android:fontFamily="arial,helvetica"
        android:hint="@string/bank_prompt"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        android:ellipsize = "none"/>
```

Please help me out with this UI change.

Thanks

**Update 1:** 
*Parent Layout code:*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14.5sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14.5sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="14.5sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14.5sp"
    tools:context=".RegistrationActivity" >
```

Comment: Ideally there shouldn't be any space to start off with, you might want to look into your array where you are defining your drop down items.

Comment: @stack_ved: If I am not wrong, this is the default behavior of the ICS style spinner. You can check the below link: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZGFW.png

Comment: you could try this attribute under Spinner android:textAlignment="viewStart"

Comment: @stack_ved: The attribute android:textAlignment="viewStart" didn't worked for me.

Comment: try my answer posted below..will work for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the spinnerinflate.xml

```
<TextView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/spinnertext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="#00f5ff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
 android:text="Text Here" >
    </TextView>
```

---

```
In your code you can set the custom Layout for spinner as
```

> MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.spinnerinflate,
>   arraylist);
>       spinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);

---

You can use SimpleAdapter as well if you don't need to have your own adapter as below

```
ArrayAdapter<String> simpleadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(YourActivityName.this, R.layout.spinnerinflate, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.yourarray));
spinner.setAdapter(simpleadapter);
```

By this inflate you can do whatever formatting you want. Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: It worked for me, but I can't set its width to match_parent. However i was successful in converting the simple drop down list to a 'simple_spinner_dropdown_item' list.

Comment: Can you help me with its layout_width, match_parent is not working for this method. Thanks. Sorry I cant VOTE UP coz I am new to StackOverFLow.

Comment: what is the problem that you are facing? In textView just do android:layout_width="fill_parent" as your image posted in the link suggests

Answer (score 1):

you can use this lines

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:textDirection="ltr" />
```

and you can increase padding from left to more space

Comment: i tested this on api 16 and work fine 
u are testing on which api level ?

Comment: I have tested this on my device with 4.2.2 (API 17)(Jelly Beans). Its not working for me. Please help me out with this.

Comment: navigate padding its not necessary i tested on adv api 17 and this code work fine maybe problem on the parent layout, you can set parent layout width to match_parent

Comment: @Sumit: I have tried -ve padding, it didnt worked for me either.

Comment: @meysam: I have updated my question with the parent layout xml code. Let me know if my parent layout is creating this issue.